# Touchbar API for web applications

Tags: javascript, api, nstouchbar, macbookpro-touch-bar

I would like to know if there is a possibility for web applications to make use of the touch bar (like a JS api).

The touchbar would be a wonderful way to navigate through a website and surely enough the guys at Apple will have noticed this as well.

Still, I can not find any trace of an API.

Comment: I would be surprised if that was possible in the same unlimited fashion as the native API exposes. A website being able to override the browser application sounds somewhere between annoying and insecure.

Comment: I am thinking in terms of displaying custom buttons in the touchbar. Like a navigation menu. I do not see any reason why this should not be done.

Comment: Because the browser already displays custom buttons in this space. If your webpage could access the Touch Bar, the browser buttons will disappear.

Comment: So the browser buttons would disappear – so what? It could be easily set in prefs if websites are allowed to overwrite those buttons. I think that the advantages of having a custom navigation set by the website is a far greater advantage than risk factor. I do hope that Apple will issue an API for this.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=178736) in Bugzilla with this feature

Comment: 3 years later and still no API available :/